# Is it possible to do a find function in SQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm looking for something like this:

Let's say we have a string..

```
$chk="pie";
```

And we want to find something in the database with the string `$chk` in it..

Say the database looks like this:

```
username realname
123pieo  Bob
ilikepie Carl
wat      Tom
```

Can I select the ones that contain `$chk` in them some how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will select any rows that contain "pie" in the username.

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE username LIKE "%pie%"
```

Comment: Thanks so much! (I have to wait 11 minutes to accept your answer) This is very helpful! :)

Comment: I suppose you wanted to write: "SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE ..." ?

Comment: @AJweb Fixed. I definitely meant that as exercise for OP :)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at MySQL's pattern matching.

From http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html.

> To find names beginning with “b”:
>
> ```
> mysql> SELECT * FROM pet WHERE name LIKE 'b%';
> +--------+--------+---------+------+------------+------------+
> | name   | owner  | species | sex  | birth      | death      |
> +--------+--------+---------+------+------------+------------+
> | Buffy  | Harold | dog     | f    | 1989-05-13 | NULL       |
> | Bowser | Diane  | dog     | m    | 1989-08-31 | 1995-07-29 |
> +--------+--------+---------+------+------------+------------+
> ```